# Python: Stop at desired time

Tags: python, time

I have some problem here. I want to stop the `print` command at desired time. I figured out some codes and it still keep looping. Here the code,

```
import time
t = time.strftime("%H%M%S")
while ti:
    print(time.strftime("%H%M%S"))
    time.sleep(1)
    if t = ("140000"): #just example of time to stop print
       break
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
import time
t = time.strftime("%H%M%S")
while t:
    t = time.strftime("%H%M%S")
    print(time.strftime("%H%M%S"))
    time.sleep(1)
    if t == ("140000"): #just example of time to stop print
       break
```

You had some bugs in your code

1. while ti:  -- > while t:
2. if t = ("140000"): --> if t=**=** ("140000"):
3. and you were missing this line t = time.strftime("%H%M%S")

Comment: Should be `>=` (and use timestamp, not string), since you have no idea how long would the loop take

Answer (score 1):

```
t = time.strftime("%H%M%S")
```

is only executed once before the loop, so `t`'s value doesn't ever change.

Your approach is the worst method of checking time difference; python's `datetime` framework allows for subtraction of timestamps and thus, you can check the time since something else happened easily without doing any string comparisons...

Answer (score 0):

`time.sleep(1)` may sleep less or more than a second therefore `t == "140000"` is not enough.

To stop a loop at a given local time:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

stop_dt = datetime.combine(datetime.now(), datetime.strptime("1400", "%H%M").time())
stop_time = time.mktime(stop_dt.timetuple())
while time.time() < stop_time:
    print(time.strftime("%H%M%S"))
    time.sleep(max(1, (stop_time - time.time()) // 2))
```

`time.time()` returns "seconds since the epoch" -- unlike strings comparison it works across a midnight.

The sleep interval is a half of the remaining time or one second (whatever larger).

`time.mktime()` may return a wrong result if stop time is during an end-of-DST transition ("fall back") when the local time is ambiguous (the string-based solution  may stop twice in this case).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import time

while ti:
    t = time.strftime("%H%M%S")
    print(time.strftime("%H%M%S"))
    time.sleep(1)
    if t = ("140000"): #just example of time to stop print
       break
```